# zsh shorten length of current path

Tags: macos, zsh, prompt

Whenever I navigate deeper into a directory, zsh displays the full path in the prompt.

Instead of displaying

`x@y:~/i/am/a/really/really/really/really/long/path/somewhere`

I would rather like to have

`x@y:~/path/somewhere`

How can I achieve this?

I'm using zsh with iTerm on OSX Yosemite 10.10.4.

EDIT:

Here is my bashrc-file:

```
  1 # System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.
  2 if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
  3    return
  4 fi
  5
  6 PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
  7 # Make bash check its window size after a process completes
  8 shopt -s checkwinsize
  9 # Tell the terminal about the working directory at each prompt.
  10 if [ "$TERM_PROGRAM" == "Apple_Terminal" ] && [ -z "$INSIDE_EMACS" ]; then
  11     update_terminal_cwd() {
  12         # Identify the directory using a "file:" scheme URL,
  13         # including the host name to disambiguate local vs.
  14         # remote connections. Percent-escape spaces.
  15         local SEARCH=' '
  16         local REPLACE='%20'
  17         local PWD_URL="file://$HOSTNAME${PWD//$SEARCH/$REPLACE}"
  18         printf '\e]7;%s\a' "$PWD_URL"
  19     }
  20     PROMPT_COMMAND="update_terminal_cwd; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
  21 fi
```

Comment: Related: [Show only current directory name (not full path) on bash prompt](http://superuser.com/q/60555/204979). In the accepted answer you can find some good information about tuning `PS1`.

Comment: The accepted answer tells something about an uppercase '\W'. I updated my question with my bashrc file. PS1 is already set to \W, so unfortunately this doesn't help me. Any further recommendations?

Comment: Consider going through the links providen in that answer. Also, the current PS1 you have does not match the definition indicated here. I would `grep` for more definitions of `PS1` in your configuration files. `grep PS1 ~/.*`

Comment: `grep PS1 ~/.*` doesn't find anything except my zsh_history. I even updated my `~/.zshrc` file but it just doesn't work. I went through all the links in that answer.

Comment: It is strange. What if you source your bashrc file? Probably `source ~/.bashrc`. If it is well defined, the prompt should change.

Comment: No changes at all. I'm at the end of my wits. :-/

Comment: Somehow, your file is either not read or not well formed, so that PS1 is not set. In https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Zsh/Guide they explain how to set PS1. I would do the test they suggest (in a new tab!) `export PS1="[Test Prompt] > "`.

Comment: `Bash` prompt escape sequences are not compatible with `zsh`

Comment: It works now. I don't know why but I had to `autoload -U promptinit` and `promptinit ` to initialize it. Thank you so much fedorqui!

Comment: @sqe ok so it worked, nice! You may want to answer your own question detailing the points that lead you to the solution, so that future readers will benefit of your experience :)

Answer (score 22):

To specify a number of shown trailing components of the path insert an integer into corresponding escape sequence in your prompt. In your case, `%2~` will do the trick. Excerpt from zshmisc(1):

```
%d 
%/     Current working directory.  If an integer follows the `%', 
       it specifies a number of trailing components of the current 
       working directory to show; zero means the whole path.  A 
       negative integer specifies leading  components, i.e. %-1d 
       specifies the first component.

%~     As  %d  and  %/, but if the current working directory starts
       with $HOME, that part is replaced by a `~'. Furthermore, if 
       it has a named directory as its prefix, that part is replaced 
       by a `~' followed by the name of the directory, but only if 
       the result is shorter than the full path; see Dynamic and 
       Static named directories in zshexpn(1).
```